# Should I get insulation for a room in my house? What are some drawbacks to wall/roof insulation?

Tags: walls, insulation, roof

In 1 room in my house on the middle floor, it gets super hot in summers and super cold in winters. So I'm thinking of getting it insulated, I've heard they put stuff like sponge/foam in the walls and roof. Bear in mind I live in India with a tropical climate, and a monsoon season. How long does insulation last (depending upon the material)? What are some drawbacks/problems with insulation that people face? How good or bad of an idea is this?

P.S: Would also like to add that in India , we have brick walls, with cement as opposed to american ones which have wood frames.

Comment: If the room has one or more outside walls, then insulation on the outside walls should help keep outside heat/cold from the room.  If the room is inside of the building, then ventilation/air movement might be better.

Comment: Insulation will last decades, even centuries. It doesn't really decompose. If you get fiberglass wet then it becomes useless. If you get rodents building homes in it then it loses effectiveness. Spray foam is the "best" choice assuming it doesn't create new vapor barrier issues.

Comment: Spray foam is also awesome for flammability.  Unfortunately, that is only an entertaining trait in *other people's* homes.  In your home it means a much faster fire that you can't escape because the extremely toxic fumes attack your nervous system and make you unable to control your feet. And a wet rag won't help with *those* fumes.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica isn't insulation foam formulated to provide at least 1 hour before it combusts?

Comment: @dandavis   Some is, but just need to look at the UK fire that not all is.  Might not be legal to use, but you want to count on someone else.

Comment: @dandavis all the people who flame-test the stuff find it combusts *immediately*.  There isn't really a way to tell a combustible to wait an hour.  There is also an epidemic of pollyanna overestimating the flame resistance of foam.  E.G. the Grenfell fire, Sunshine mine, and dear God! The Browns Ferry nuclear plant. More likely the installation instructions tell you that you must surround the stuff with 1-hour firestop - e.g. fire blocking between studs, thick drywall on the walls, etc. But a plastic receptacle box will penetrate that and be a vector for draft and toxic gases.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica What material would you recommend?

Comment: @crip659 Can you elaborate? What kind of insulation would the outer wall have?

Comment: @johnnytest fiberglass or rockwool. If you're looking for an insulation material that will also serve as building cladding, that's probably not going to happen. Buildings aren't built that way. Don't forget the roof and consider painting the roof white to reduce solar gain.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica Does it last long? And will it survive the monsoons?

Comment: @Johnnytest insulation does not go on the exterior of a house.  The job of insulation is not to protect buildings from weather, the building needs exterior cladding to do that.